# Update date in database - attend button

Tags: python, django, database, button, controller

Hej, 
I have a problem with updating current date. I should click the button "attend" and update status with current date in database. For me everything looks fine but I have no clue where is the problem.. Maybe someone could find my mistake?

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="/donors/">
                    {% csrf_token %}
<button 
type="submit" class="btn attendBtn" value="{{ item.id }}" name="attend"> attend </button>
```

VIEW:

```
elif 'attend' in request.GET:
        donor_id = None
        # if request.method == "GET":
        #     donor_id = request.GET.get('id')

        if donor_id:
            donor = Donor.objects.get(id=int(donor_id))
            if donor:
                donor.lastAttendance.add(datetime.datetime.now())
                donor.save()
```

DATABASE:
[database link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYze0.png)

Any help will appreciated!

Comment: you are sending data by post request from Front end and getting it via GET request from back end ? seriously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is a POST, so the data will be in `request.POST`, not `request.GET`.

Also note you never actually get `donor_id` from anywhere, it will always be None. If you want it to have the value of the button, you again need to use `request.POST['attend']`.